MS Edge and Chrome Fails to connect to Website
We have a IIS 7.5 server on Windows 2012 R2. We disabled older TLS 1.0 and 1.1 protocols with only TLS 1.2 enabled. Since then only firefox can connect to the website. Edge and Chrome fail at Client Hello with message ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.
Wireshark shows that Edge is using TSLv1 at Record layer while firefox uses TLSv1.2. The Windows 10 Client PC only has TLS 1.2 enabled.

